# What happens when auto increment get a duplicate?

Tags: sql

my primary key auto increment reached its maximum value (assume 5) but I have unused numbers (because of deletion) (assume 1 & 3). if I reset the auto increment using this code:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name AUTO_INCREMENT = 1
```

if I inserted 2 new rows now what will happen? will it skip 2 and insert it as 3?
or will it generate an error?

Comment: it will take you several minutes to validate behavior of your RDMS

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product (and `auto_increment` is non-standard SQL). Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using - presumably MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

auto_increment will increment row by row , so it will not skip 2 and will give 2 and 3 respectively to two rows

Answer (score 0):

It will generate an error.

It won't skip value 2 and it'll try to insert this Id ...

... but if there's a key constraint to disallow duplicate Id's then it'll throw a key violation error.

You'd need to remove the IDENTITY attribute if it exists and create your own logic to decide the number to insert which could then be applied as a default